# How to encode entire html response data and then decode it via JS?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, encoding

I would like to encode all data being fetched by an ajax request (so the data has to be encoded on the server side) and then once the data is received by the client it will be decoded via JS and then processed as readable HTML data.

I am using PHP to render the data on the server. What is the most efficient,fastest,easiest way?

Thanks!

Comment: By encode, are you saying you want to use php's urlencode and decode it via decodeURIComponent() in JS?

Comment: Yes something like that. I am thinking about using PHP's base_64_encode but what is the javascript equivalent of a decode for that?

Comment: there is nothing built-in for it, but people have ported others. http://ostermiller.org/calc/encode.html Check out the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not trying to reinvent HTTP Request / Response are you? if so, ditch the AJAX and just request a page.

If however you are just trying to load up "some" HTML content to dump into a container on the page then jQuery has a simple method called `.load()`

http://api.jquery.com/load

**Update:** based on the discussion in the comments, here is an ***insecure*** quick-n-dirty obfuscation technique between PHP on the server and JS on the client using [ROT13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13).

*Again I'd like to emphasize that this answer is just about a technique - since there is nothing gained from this process other than additional overhead - Thus I wouldn't recommend using it.*

```
<?php
  function rot13($s){
    return !$s ? "" : strtr($s,
      "NnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZzAaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMm",
      "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz");
  }
  //encode the HTML content
  $encodedStr = rot13($originalHTML);
?>
```

Then once you've sent it to the browser, decode it in JavaScript:

```
String.prototype.rot13 = function(){
  return this.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, function(c){
    return String.fromCharCode((c <= "Z" ? 90 : 122) >= (c = c.charCodeAt(0) + 13) ? c : c - 26);
  });
};
//decode the HTML content
 var decodedHTML = ajaxResponseHTML.rot13();
```

Comment: I want to do this for security reasons, for example if a ajax request is directly accessed through the address bar the output seen will be encoded.

Comment: @Johnny - this won't work either then.  In order for the "encrypted" content to be "decrypted" by JavaScript, the technique and/or any "keys" would be totally visible in plain text.  Therefore you can't actually decrypt in JavaScript to obtain "security".

Comment: It is ok if the technique is visible I just don't want the data ajax to render if accessed directly in the address bar

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understand what problem you are trying to solve, however I will add this.  If the user has permission to access your site (e.g. the site is free, or they are a logged in user) then the user can see 100% of all of your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript if they want to regardless how it was passed (e.g. AJAX or otherwise)

Comment: I know that. What I am trying to solve is that the html recieved from ajax requests conducted is raw HTML code like :<div>blah</div>. This data can be rendered by the browser, however if this data is encoded the html response will not give readable code which will prevent the browser from rendering elements and instead display text, unless ofcourse the decoder in the ajax script decodes the html first. So I am trying to encode this response data so when it is accessed directly it will appear as encoded text instead of HTML objects

Comment: @Johnny - I get how it would work... what I don't get is why you would want to do it?  It seems like a lot of effort and overhead for something that will not benefit 99.999% of users nor aid in making the server/system more secure, faster, or improve performance.  That said if you are determined to apply an extra level of code translation I'd probably just apply a ROT13 encoding on the server and a decoder in JavaScript.  It will "uglify" the code yet is easy to implement on both server and client.

Answer (score 0):

Communicate with PHP through JSON, with `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`.